# How to resize image from file get content

Tags: php, codeigniter, upload

I'm using codeigniter and i want to resize image from user that upload via url.

Here is my code:

```
            //upload via url
            $url = $this->input->post('photo');
            /* Extract the filename */
            $filename = substr($url, strrpos($url, '/') + 1);
            /* Save file wherever you want */
            file_put_contents('myuploads/'.$filename, file_get_contents($url));
            //resize start
            $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
            $config['source_image']  = $filename;
            $config['overwrite']     = TRUE;
            $config['width'] = 59;
            $config['height'] = 90;
            $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
            $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
            $this->image_lib->resize();
            $data=array(
                'username'=>$this->input->post('username'),
                'deskrip'=>$this->input->post('deskrip'),
                'photo'=>$filename
              );
            $this->db->where('id',$id);
            $outp = $this->db->update('user',$data);
```

Upload is working but the problem is the image won't resize into 59x90 and still in original size.

Any answer?

Many thanks..

Comment: First run phpinfo(); and see if gd2 is an installed module.

Comment: Did you try to debug? What did work? Where does it stop working?

Answer (score 0):

resize() method is working or not you can see error by  :

```
    if ( ! $this->image_lib->resize())
{
    echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
}
```

see [Documentation](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/image_lib.html)
There is a nice tutorial of image Manipulation ,from  [tutsplus](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/codeigniter-from-scratch-file-uploading-and-image-manipulation--net-9452)

Hope this help you.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Might be a bit off-topic (not through codeigniter), but I found this method to be a little easier in my project.

I used this logic to do a cropping logic for pictures.

```
$value = "picture.jpg";
$x = $p[0];
$y = $p[1];
$w = $p[2];
$h = $p[3];

$targ_w = $w;
$targ_h = $h;
$jpeg_quality = 90;

$src = REAL_PATH."uploads/".$value;
$src_end = $path."/".$value;
$ext = pathinfo($src, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
if(($ext == "jpg" || $ext == "jpeg") && isset($x) && isset($y) && isset($w))
{
    $img_r = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
    $dst_r = ImageCreateTrueColor( $targ_w, $targ_h );

    imagecopyresampled($dst_r,$img_r,0,0,$x,$y,
    $targ_w,$targ_h,$w,$h);
    unlink($src);
    imagejpeg($dst_r,$src_end,$jpeg_quality);
}
```